# Proving $P(A \cap B) \geq 1- P(A^c) - P(B^c)$

Tags: probability, proof-writing, solution-verification

I have already seen other ways to do this math stack exchange, I just want to know if this is a valid proof.

Prove  $P(A \cap B)  \geq 1- P(A^c) - P(B^c)$ 
$P(A \cap B)  \geq  P(A)- (1- P(B))$ 
$P(A \cap B)  \geq  P(A) + P(B) -1 $ 
$ 1  \geq  P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ 
$ P(A \cup B) \leq 1$ (Second axiom)

QED

Comment: Looks fine for me.

Comment: Method seems fine.